# Content search config: not able to filter by date

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, content-search-web-part

I have built a simple content search web part based on a blog (posts).

When it comes down to filter by published date (there are blog posts published 'in the future' that do show up in the query results that should not show up) I am not able to configure. See below for pic, the value PublishedDateOWSDATE is a standard mapped field that is the published date of the blog.

My query would just be filter the posts that have a pubished date 'less than' today.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create another Managed property with the published date. Now the filtering works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `Managed Property` `PublishedDateOWSDATE` in your search schema and identify what data type is it, `Date Time` or `Text`?

If its `Text` then you will get such syntax error, because you can’t use Today when you’re mapped to a text field.